# String to dialog alert null

Tags: android

I have a string data and I want to make this data appears in dialog alert.I  have already applied in dialog alert message but its showing still null.

this is in my question class

```
 private String mPembahasan[]= {
            "Konsumsi ayam",
            "Konsumsi sapi"
    };


public  String getCorrectbahas (int a){
        String bahas = mPembahasan[a];
        return bahas;
    }
```

this in my quiz class

```
  private String mBahas;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
     private void gameOver(){
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Quiz.this);
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Game Over! Skor Latihan Anda "    + mScore * 10  +  " Poin")
                    .setMessage(mBahas)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Latihan Soal Baru",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Quiz.class));

                                }
                            }
                    )
                    .setNegativeButton("Keluar",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                                }
                            }
                    );
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

thank you for your help

Comment: you don't assing anything to `mBahas`. Therefore it is null

Comment: yes but know im confuse where to assing mBahas,  becasue is not to textview or button but to alertdialog

Comment: you can do it for example in the first line of `gameOver` method

Comment: can you make example please? thankyou

Comment: add `mBahas = <whatever you need>` as the first line of `gameOver(){` method

Comment: okey i will try thanks

Comment: im already try to getCorrecbahas but cant solved

Comment: `but cant solved` what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

in your dialog you set null string `.setMessage(mBahas)` .

replace this line

`.setMessage(mBahas)`

To

`.setMessage(getCorrectbahas(0));`

one more thing you have to change

```
 private String mPembahasan[]= {
            "Konsumsi ayam",
            "Konsumsi sapi"
    };
```

To :

```
private String[] mPembahasan= {"Konsumsi ayam", "Konsumsi sapi"};
```

Comment: where did you `getCorrectbahas` put this method. inside activity or calling from some where else ?

Comment: another activity sir. getCoreectbahas in question class. my alartdialog in quiz class

Comment: im relize my  private String mBahas; is suggested neveruse i think i need added somethink

Answer (score 0):

move  gameOver  function out of onCreate and initialize the variable like this

```
private String mBahas;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    mBahas=getCorrectbahas(0)
    gameOver();
 }
```

function

```
private void gameOver(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Quiz.this);
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Game Over! Skor Latihan Anda "    + mScore * 10  +  " Poin")
                .setMessage(mBahas)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Latihan Soal Baru",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Quiz.class));

                            }
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("Keluar",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                            }
                        }
                );
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```